# Django text in form is not translating

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my forms.py:

```
def field_validate(self, request):
    try:
        id_exists(request, self["user"].data)
    except:
        self.add_error('user', ugettext_lazy("id is not available"))
```

the problem is when my 'user' filed is not validated in my field_validate function, the error is displayed in English, however other texts in my whole project are translating. using ugettext_lazy nor ugettext solved the problem.

Is there anything I am missing?

tnx

Comment: It is `validate` or `clean` method?

Comment: its my custom validation function..clean is working respectively

Comment: that was not actually my exact code, I had changed the names and some extra codes to be more clear here, i updated my post for no further misunderstanding @AnupYadav

Comment: Have you added and compiled message? Are you checking it with correct locale settings?

Comment: yes both are done. Setting is fine because my whole project is okay. @gonczor

Comment: And how do you test it? With unittests or "by hand"?

Comment: by hand @gonczor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was because in django.po file, above the translation there was a ***#fuzzy*** that prevented the option to be translated!